# IOS 64-bit porting issue with T1SignaturePoint CGRectValue

Tags: ios8

Below code is not working with 64-bit architecture and `IOS-8.0` version

```
CGRect r1 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue];
```

Error:

> 2015-06-04 19:18:45.933 MySampleCloset UAT[40174:865394]
>   -[T1SignaturePoint CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0 2015-06-04 19:18:45.977 MySampleCloset
>   UAT[40174:865394] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[T1SignaturePoint
>   CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Please suggest the solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with 64-bit. Whatever a T1SignaturePoint is, it has no `CGRectValue` method. That's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As a part of porting the application to 64bit, we have changed IOS version to 8.2 then we are getting this issue.
Pl see the outputs for 32bit and 64bits for "signature.rawPoints"
32bit IOS less than 8.0 version output :
(
        "NSRect: {{130, 142.5}, {2.3333333, 100}}",
        "NSRect: {{136, 139.5}, {2.4990008, 101}}",
        "NSRect: {{152.25, 131}, {2.0691545, 102}}",
        "NSRect: {{169.75, 121}, {1.7328094, 103}}",
        "NSRect: {{185.25, 111}, {1.5653242, 104}}",
        "NSRect: {{196.125, 104}, {1.6099705, 105}}",
        "NSRect: {{200.75, 101.375}, {1.9532523, 106}}"
    ),

64bit IOS8.2 version output:
(
        "\nlocation: 87.000000,112.000000\nvelocity: 0.000000,0.000000\nacceleration: 0.000000,0.000000\ntimestamp: 19476.794956\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.666667\nid: 100",
        "\nlocation: 88.000000,116.000000\nvelocity: 22.341108,89.364433\nacceleration: 499.125115,1996.500461\ntimestamp: 19476.839717\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 5.006714\nid: 101",
        "\nlocation: 92.000000,125.000000\nvelocity: 228.450167,514.012876\nacceleration: 11771.412252,24252.751985\ntimestamp: 19476.857226\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.700317\nid: 102",
        "\nlocation: 97.000000,134.000000\nvelocity: 298.178096,536.720573\nacceleration: 4158.268213,1354.187550\ntimestamp: 19476.873995\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.437694\nid: 103")

In fact we need to get the rect values for the below code
CGRect r1 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue];

when I tried to print the below code with IOS less than 8.0 version
Code: [[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue]
output : {130, 142.5}

But with IOS version 8.2 and with 64bit we are getting following output
OUTPUT:
location: 87.000000,112.000000
velocity: 0.000000,0.000000
acceleration: 0.000000,0.000000
timestamp: 19476.794956
And when we execute the following code, we are getting the following error
Code: CGRect r1 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue];
Error: 
2015-06-04 19:18:45.933 MySampleCloset UAT[40174:865394] -[T1SignaturePoint CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0 2015-06-04 19:18:45.977 MySampleCloset UAT[40174:865394] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[T1SignaturePoint CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0'